# Reusing style trigger in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have done some research on this but failed to find out on how to reuse the style trigger.

I have style trigger set on Label and I am using Data trigger to set content. I have multiple labels in same view and also in different view. The Data bound is of same type except its different property of same data context.

Consider following 2 different labels where I need to display performance of 2 person - PersonA and PersonB. The value displayed for both the labels will be based on Performance format selected.

```
<Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="9"
HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
<Label.Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource SomeGlobalStaticStyle}" TargetType="Label">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PersonModel.PerformanceFormat}" Value="Fractional">
                <Setter Property="Content"  Value="{Binding DataModel.PersonA.Performance.Value.Fractional}"  />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PersonModel.PerformanceFormat}" Value="Decimal">
                <Setter Property="Content"  Value="{Binding DataModel.PersonA.Performance.Value.Decimal}" />                    
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PersonModel.PerformanceFormat}" Value="US">
                <Setter Property="Content"  Value="{DataModel.PersonA.Performance.Value.US}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Label.Style>
```

```
<Label Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="9"
HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
<Label.Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource SomeGlobalStaticStyle}" TargetType="Label">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PersonModel.PerformanceFormat}" Value="Fractional">
                <Setter Property="Content"  Value="{Binding DataModel.PersonB.Performance.Value.Fractional}"  />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PersonModel.PerformanceFormat}" Value="Decimal">
                <Setter Property="Content"  Value="{Binding DataModel.PersonB.Performance.Value.Decimal}" />                    
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PersonModel.PerformanceFormat}" Value="US">
                <Setter Property="Content"  Value="{DataModel.PersonB.Performance.Value.US}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Label.Style>
```

If you see, the only difference is the first trigger takes PersonA and the second trigger takes PersonB. I have 10 instances of such label spread in same and multiple views. Is there is way I can define this trigger once in Resources and bind whatever data I want to from each Label.

Looking forward for the solution.

Regards,
Abdyax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

configurate setters to obtain values not from Label DataContext, but another Label property - Tag

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource SomeGlobalStaticStyle}" TargetType="Label">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PersonModel.PerformanceFormat}" Value="Fractional">
            <Setter Property="Content"  Value="{Binding Tag.Performance.Value.Fractional, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}}"  />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PersonModel.PerformanceFormat}" Value="Decimal">
            <Setter Property="Content"  Value="{Binding Tag.Performance.Value.Decimal, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PersonModel.PerformanceFormat}" Value="US">
            <Setter Property="Content"  Value="{Binding Tag.Performance.Value.US, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and bind labels Tag to different properties:

```
<Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="9"
HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Tag="{Binding DataModel.PersonA}"/>

<Label Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="9"
HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Tag="{Binding DataModel.PersonB}"/>
```

both labels should pick our default style for `TargetType="Label"` with triggers

Comment: Probably best to use an explicit style rather than implicit, as there may be plenty of unrelated labels out there, and you don't want to override their content.  Otherwise, a perfectly cromulent solution.

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there is way I can define this trigger once in Resources and bind whatever data I want to from each Label.

Short answer: No, I am afraid not. You cannot replace the `Value` of a `Setter` but reuse the rest of the Style in XAML.

You could create the styles programmatically using the [XamlReader.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc663033(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Then you can simply replace the "PersonA" with "PersonB" in the `string` that you pass to the method.

But there is no way to do this generally in pure XAML.

Comment: It is certainly possible.  All of the necessary building blocks are there: (1) evaluation of property paths is dynamic; (2) the `DataContext` of individual labels can be overridden; and (3) the bindings on each `DataTrigger` could be made to bind relative to the view's `DataContext` rather than the label's.  Alternatively, one could use the `Tag` property as a storage location for the `Person` instance, as @ASh describes.  It can be done, reasonably, and there is more than one way to do it.

Comment: "You cannot replace the Value of a Setter but reuse the rest of the Style in XAML". This is not possible. Binding to the Tag property is indeed possible in this particular case though. But it still only works if the Value property is exactly the same.

Comment: An important caveat, but a moot one in this case, as OP indicated the data types are the same, and the bindings only differed in their relative binding root.

Comment: "But there is no way to do this *generally* in pure XAML."

Comment: When I said "it is certainly possible", I was referring to what OP asked, and not your specific assertion that you cannot replace the value of a setter, which is true.  I admit I could have been more specific.

Comment: Me too I guess :)