# One DataTrigger for multiple properties

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a listview bound to an Observable collection, the listview has properties that most of them will use the same trigger.
is it possible to define the trigger once in the resource section and just refer to it once needed by the properties ?

so far i come to this :

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="Pstyle">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Testing"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding P1}" Value="Testing">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGreen"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

and in the listview member i just apply the defined style to the propertie P1

```
 Style="{DynamicResource Pstyle}"
```

but how to apply the same defined trigger for let say P2, P3, P4...

Comment: Did you consider using a mulit-binding?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reusing style trigger in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215397/reusing-style-trigger-in-wpf)

Comment: @thatguy unfortunatly no, because still in the trigger they referance the PersonModel.PerformanceFormat, i have 30 properties "P1--> P30" and all should have the same behavior. i dont want to write a duplicated code for all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to put your trigger logic on the content of the `TextBlock`, in my opinion you should use a `Trigger` targeting `Text` property, instead of a `DataTrigger`.

Check out this sample code:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="Pstyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="Testing">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGreen"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock1" Text="MyTextBlock1Text" Style="{StaticResource Pstyle}"/>
<TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock2" Text="MyTextBlock2Text" Style="{StaticResource Pstyle}"/>
<TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock3" Text="MyTextBlock3Text" Style="{StaticResource Pstyle}"/>
```

as you can see there is only one single style applied to different `Textblock`s.

Then you should adapt this to your listview.